# an exe created in vs2008 which uses Interop assemblies can it deployed anywhere?

Tags: c#, clr, office-interop

this is a fairly lame question that i am asking but i wanted to know if a small program that uses Microsoft Office Interop assemblies be deployed elsewhere? will it be supported without any .NET clr...i went through a couple of solutions but i really haven't got a clue

Comment: where will it be deployed? windows server? version etc.  Chances are the place you're deploying will have .net runtime

Comment: @christiandev i want to run it in another windows machine, it's an addon for excel..so is there any possibilty of it working anywhere

Answer (score 1):

> will it be supported without any .NET clr.

No, it won't. Managed code requires a CLR in order to run.

Comment: one more thing, i really am a beginner so, do normal machines running windows have .net clr installed, and will those interop assemblies cause any problem, i have written an application which i want to run in any windows machine.

Comment: ive found this inside project properties>publish>application files, i've included my assembly files over there, is there any gurantee it'll work..

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to check on the machine it will be deployed on? if so, look to see if it already has .net - very unlikely that it wouldn't.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework

If not, you could look at creating a deployment package for the prerequisites
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms165429%28v=vs.80%29.aspx.

The destination machines will also need the correct version of excel installed.